# How to access a simple file or folder from Tomcat webapps folder

Tags: tomcat, tomcat6

I want to be able to access a folder from my tomcat webapps folder so that I can give someone a URL like:

http://localhost:8080/myFolder/myFile.f

And in a web browser if they point to this they should start downloading the file.

But in reality I get a 404 error when I try to point to this location.

How can I solve this or get around it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can also place the folder inside the default servlet. For your example, the folder would be:

```
/webapps/ROOT/myFolder/
```

Comment: This is neat, but somehow does not work for me with symbolic link underneath. What works for me is a symbolic link in /webapps. In conjuntion with https://serverfault.com/a/143683/142353 I managed to serve a directory somewhere else on the host system (/var/log/tomcat6) :D

Answer (score 6):

Make your folder a web application: put a WEB-INF folder with a minimal web.xml file into your folder, the web.xml file could look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN" "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">
<web-app>
</web-app>
```

Then configure Tomcat to deploy the webapp with the URI you want.

Comment: OK this worked for me.  Basically "have a WEB-INFO/web.xml file" then within tomcat, something like `mkdir webapps/<your web app name>/myFolder` then touch something there.  It should become available on "http://your_hostname:8080/<your web app name>/myFolder/MyFile.f"

Comment: Found a neat extension: "enabling directory index". see http://wiki.metawerx.net/wiki/EnablingOrDisablingDirectoryListingsUsingWeb.xml